# Design of a differential pair

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-design, design, current-mirror

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRzyIH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
**Problem:**

I need to design a differential pair with a gain of **30dB**

To make this design I have to used 4 mosfets transistor 2n7000 with these characteristics

- M1:

  - \$V_t = 1.36\$ V
  - \$V_a = 4.729\$ V
- M2:

  - \$V_t = 1.6\$ V
  - \$V_a = 5.6\$ V
- M3:

  - \$V_t = 1.5\$ V
  - \$V_a = 4.2\$ V
- M1:

  - \$V_t = 1.35\$ V
  - \$V_a = 3.3\$ V

**Characteristics:**

To make the design I have to use two mosfets for a differential pair with passive load and two mosfets for a current mirror.

I can't find the \$V_s\$ of the differential pair that come from the current mirror \$V_d\$

Comment: Please add a schematic to your question using the built-in schematic editor.

Comment: I already upload it